# Reset select option after correct answer

Tags: javascript, html

Long time listener, first time caller...I have a music test that asks the user to identify a pitch and after the correct answer, I need the select option's value to reset to 'disabled selected.' Have tried multiple things but no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```js
$("#pitchBtn").click(function() {
      if (gameFinished) {
        // Clear the value of the option in the select element here
       }
}
```

```html
<select id="selectText">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Enter your guess</option>
        <option value="C"></option>
        <option value="D">D</option>
        <option value="E">E</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense to select an element that can't be selected.

Comment: @Quentin Without selecting it most browsers will jump to the next option. Seems valid if unusual. In this case the OP seems to want to default to "Enter your guess" but not allow it to be selected once the select is opened. Without the selected attribute the next option would be chosen by default.

Comment: target the select, `for (const elem of document.querySelectorAll('select'))
  elem.selectedIndex = null` – or target the option, `for (const elem of document.querySelectorAll('option[selected]')) elem.selected = false`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var element = document.getElementById('selectText');
element.value = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest:

```
// cache the relevant <option> element,
// retrieve that element using
// document.querySelectorAll() to select
// the first, if any, element matching the
// supplied CSS selector:
let defaultOption = document.querySelectorAll('option[value=""]');

// set the 'selected' property to true:
defaultOption.selected = true;

// set the 'disabled' property to true:
defaultOption.disabled = true;
```